# Is it possible to get Message Box in web forms?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dialog

I tried but I guess Message Box only works with win forms. What is the best alternative to use in web forms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `confirm` for yes/no questions and `alert` for "OK" messages in JavaScript.

The other alternative is to use JavaScript to pop up a new window that looks and acts like a message box.  Modality in this case varied by browser.  In Internet Explorer, the method

```
window.showModalDialog(url,name,params)
```

will display a modal dialog.  The Mozilla approach is to still use

```
window.open(url,name,params)
```

but add `modal=yes` to the `params` list.

Answer (score 2):

```
result = confirm('Yes or no question here.')
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
alert("This box has an OK button.");
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax ModalPopup also works nicely.  Here is an example:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have dojo dialog widget: http://www.dojotoolkit.org/ and you can use it as a message box.